# Oracle Database 12C Cannot Start After Shutdown

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I was able to login to sqlplus with my credentials to do the `SHUTDOWN` command. It worked and the database shutdown. But now when I try to login again with the same credentials to start the server back up, it says: "ORA-01033:  ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress". How can I log in to sqlplus and use the `STARTUP` command?

This is on Linux Debian - Oracle 12C.

EDIT: I shutdown the database to import a copy of old oradata contents.

Answer (score 2):

Login with operating system credentials that don't require the database to be open:

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
```

If things are really messed up you might need to connect using the `prelim` option:

```
C:\> sqlplus -prelim / as sysdba
```

If the database is hung and not shutting down properly sometimes you need to do a `shutdown abort` and then start it back up:

```
SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
```

This is also possible with the `srvctl` command but in my experience it's not as reliable as a SQL*Plus `shutdown abort`.

Comment: Ah thank you, but unfortunately when I do this, the problem still exists, even after multiple hours of waiting.

Comment: In that case you'll probably want to check the alert log for any errors or weird messages.  If there's nothing in there, maybe check `crsctl status resource -t` (if you're using RAC or ASM) - perhaps one of the dependencies was not brought up, like maybe the diskgroup isn't mounted.